# "Still better than" informal translation -- X 还是比 Y 好 abbreviation

Tags: translation, mandarin

I want to say "X is still better than Y :)" in a kind of joking/offhand manner. This is just a simple text message, so I would further like to abbreviate it like: "still better than Y :)"

My understanding is I can express the original like:

`AllenNlp 还是比 FairSeq 好 :）`

Is the abbreviated version 
`还是比 FairSeq 好 :）`?

Are there any general rules for "texting" chinese?

Comment: I wonder if `Y还是不如X` works.

Comment: @Becky 李蓓 yeah, I agree that, but it is a little bit negative. lol   
so I'll say `X比較好`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AllenNlp 还是比 FairSeq 好 :）`

It is more natural for me to keep the first half. It can be shortened to:

`还是 AllenNlp 好` or `还是 AllenNlp 更好`

As another object does not exist, '比' is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is closest to what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

`还是比 FairSeq 好` It's a correct using.

And it can also using like:

`AllenNlp 比較好` (AllenNlp  is better)

Answer (score 1):

> still better than Y

Use 還是比Y好 is sufficiently to express what you want in the context. It suits your need. Still(還是) better(好) than(比) Y. 還是比Y好 is acceptable to use if the people know what thing that you mean is still better than Y.